# Gparted for android

Tags: file-system, partitions

I would like to partition my sd cards using gparted on android.

I would like NTFS support along with the standard EXT formats.

Is this possible?

Comment: Why would you want to have NTFS on Android? Afraid even if you could create an NTFS partition, Android wouldn't be able to use it. AFAIK there is no native NTFS support, at least not on most devices. Might help if you specified your device and Android version.

Comment: Why don't you just use a pc to partition them with gparted?

Comment: @jiggunjer interesting because it sounds like a fun idea.  Honestly I am partly trying to use Phoenix OS as a boot cd so I would like to see if I could get gparted run on the boot cd.

Comment: @Izzy I don't care if I can access it from android just looking to partition.  I'm running KitKat on a motorola.

Comment: @Izzy Not native, but there is. Paragon made their NTFS driver available on android long ago: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.paragon.mounter They claim it also works for SD cards.

Comment: @TJJ Yeah, there are [even some more](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_storagemedia) :)

Comment: old and effective method ... just follow the steps https://forum.xda-developers.com/crossdevice-dev/sony/ntfs-mount-tool-android-t2920856

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android surely don't have GParted. However a CLI version of GNU `parted` is available in a variety of custom recovery builds. Even if not, you can find a static build of parted easily with a little Googling. Transfer it to your phone, reboot to recovery and run it with 'adb shell'.

Comment: Well, there's [AParted](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sylkat.AParted) on Android ;)

Answer (score 0):

In most Android kernels is the header file "(Kernel root)/fs/ntfs/ntfs.h" already there, but nothing else. You have to download ntfs-3g and compile it together with the kernel - what means, you have to dig into the Android/ARM Kernel development for your device. But beside of that, for (Micro) SD/SDXC storage devices, NTFS (as long with other Journaling Filesystems) is the worst recommendation (SD Flash difference to SSD Flash,  Wearleveling etc.)